# Two "identical" answers to a request (utf8 and non-utf8)

Tags: utf-8, sparql, dbpedia

I am having problems with a live.dbpedia SPARQL request, for it returns some entries twice (once as an utf8 URI, once as a non-utf8 URI : [Here are the results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fname%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fname%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3AIndividual_graphs%3E.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20desc%28%3Fname%29%20LIMIT%202%20%20%20&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Is it something that needs to be fixed inside of dbpedia (where should it be reported)?

Is there a way to keep only one version of these duplicated urls? (I do not want to ignore a non-utf8 URI if there is no utf8 counterpart)

P.S.: The actual request

```
select distinct ?name where {
   ?name <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject><http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Individual_graphs>.
   } ORDER BY desc(?name) LIMIT 2
```

Comment: What duplicated results are you getting?  When I run that query, I get two results.  "Young-Fibonnaci lattice" and "Watkins snark".  Update: my mistake, I ran that on the typical DBpedia endpoint http://dbpedia.org/sparql.  Rereading your question, I see that you're using http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql, and there I get the same results you've mentioned.

Comment: Ah, in DBpedia (non-live), you get the Watkins snark result too, but the limit 2 made it not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there are multiple URIs that can identify the article, they all have the same article title, so you can extract the title (it's the value of the rdfs:label property), group by that, and then sample the URIs.  Doing that, along with using the built-in DBpedia namespaces, I end up with this query:

```sql
select distinct (sample(?name_) as ?name) where {
  ?name_ dcterms:subject category:Individual_graphs ;
        rdfs:label ?label
}
group by ?label
order by desc(?name)
```

[SPARQL results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%28sample%28%3Fname_%29%20as%20%3Fname%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fname_%20dcterms%3Asubject%20category%3AIndividual_graphs%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Flabel%0D%0Aorder%20by%20desc%28%3Fname%29%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: I just tried that but there is still "Brouwer%E2%80%93Haemers_graph" among the results. Is it because 'sample' just 'picks one' without letting you select which?

Comment: @NathannCohen Yes, sample will pick one arbitrarily.  I don't know whether there's a way to prefer an IRI over a URI, but I could adjust the query to avoid ones with % in them.  I'll update soon...

Comment: @NathannCohen Actually, if you search for graphs with Brouwer in the name, e.g., with [this query](http://pastebin.com/5i1Qt5fU), there's no result without the percent escaping, even though it's linked to a URI without it by owl:sameAs... We might be able to make this work...